# Converting float into time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

i have a string value 20.30(hours) i need it to convert 08:30:00 .
Can any one know this please help me.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    double time = 20.30;
    double timeInSeconds = time*24*60*60; // 0.27392 * 24 = 6.57408 hours *60 for minutes * 60 for seconds

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeInSeconds]; //Creates a date: 1 January 2001 6:34:27 AM, GMT

    NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
    [dateFormat release];
```

The above code does not working for me.

Comment: I think what you need to do is create a date formatter with format @"hh.mm" to match your string. Then use this formatter to create an NSDate object from the string. You then need another formatter with the output format @"hh:mm:ss" and then use this to turn your NSDate into a string! Hope this helps,

Comment: Also just a note, not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with timeInSeconds? Since 20:30 is not 20.30*24*3600 seconds from now unless you get very luck with when you make the call.

Comment: Agrees with @GeorgeGreen's first comment.. check out my answer

Comment: DownVoting without providing proper reason is not good...

Comment: @Melbourne I haven't downvoted.. I said **DownVoting without providing proper reason is not good...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your Code with this:

```
//The Format which you want as output
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

//The Format in which your dateTime currently is
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat1.dateFormat = @"HH.mm";
[dateFormat1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

double time = 20.30;

NSString *timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",time];
NSDate *dates = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:timeStr];
NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:dates]);
```

Comment: this doesnot convert the time properly. 20.5 hours comes up as 20:50:00 which is wrong. it should come up as 20:30:00

Comment: @Izac,I appreciate your contribution, But if you have a closer look at the question The very first line says **"string value 20.30(hours) i need it to convert 08:30:00"** Which indirectly says that 20.5 = 8:50:00 and not 8:30:00.Also as you have changed `hh` to `HH` stating it as wrong. I would like to let you know that small `hh` is for 12 hours format and capital `HH` is for 24 hours format. And since in the quest he has specified that he needs 20.30 to be converted as 8:30:00 which again means he wants 12 hour format.So here again I am correct. So as per the question I m correct in all ways

Comment: hmmm... didnt know that "HH: and hh" thing... and its good to learn. i just percieved the question wrong.thanks and my apologies man..

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm 'on' dd MMMM YYYY"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using to compute the seconds is wrong.

You may use something like

```
double t = 20.30;

int hours = (int) floor(t);
int minutes = (int) ((t-hours)*100);

int seconds = hours*60*60 + minutes*60;

NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
double time = 20.30;
NSString *strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",time];
NSArray *values = [strTime componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

double hours = [values objectAtIndex:0];
double min = [values objectAtIndex:1];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(hours*60*60)+mins*60]; 
NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

double time = 20.30;
NSString* timeString=[NSString stringWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",time]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@":"]];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:timeString];
dateFormat.dateFormat=@"hh:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

this converts 20.30 to 08:30:00